# Nodejs Throwing following error

Tags: node.js, macos, babeljs, restify

I am running rest api using node and restify on mac-book. I am not sure why I am getting following error. I tried updating npm packages but nothing work. Thanks in advance!!

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::7088
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1330:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1465:7)
at Server.listen (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:404:32)
at spawnWorker (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/src/server.js:20:10)
at run (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/src/server.js:81:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/src/server.js:86:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at loader (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Server.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rahul/Development/projects/inventory-manager/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
 error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
 error: Script restart attempt #22
  events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Comment: You are deploying a server listening in a port already used by another process. Change the listening port or stop the other process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Why was my `node` process not able to boot up?

**A:** This is the reason why your application was dying.

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::7088

It means that another process is already on port `7088` and your `node` process was not able to bind to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using nodemon which starts the port 7088 at npm start but never kills it on npm stop. So it's confusing and I have to kill the port every time I update something. Do you have any solution on this?

Comment: Maybe you can try killing the node process boot by `nodemon` in the script that you are executing by `npm stop`. I have never used `nodemon` so I'm not sure. But this sounds like a pretty common problem, maybe search around stackoverflow more or ask another question. I'll also recommend checking the `nodemon` doco.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem couple of times before,
Just change the port for node from 7088 to any other port